# Civimail Mailings not saving or "corrupting"

Tags: civimail

I very recently took over custodianship of a drupal CiviCRM, so I don't really have a clue what I'm doing. Bear with me.

I'm on civi 4.6.2 on drupal, and ever since the upgrade, the mailings have gone completely haywire on me.  back when I could upload a .html file, everything worked fine, but now, it's all wonky.

When I first paste the html in, everything looks fine in the WYSIWYG screen, but when I save it, one of several things happens:  It simply doesn't save the changes to the HTML email field (though the new subject and plaintext fields save perfectly fine).  Once, I got it to save the HTML, but it stripped out large chunks of that, and put in the HTML Special entity codes next to a bunch (but not all) of the spaces and quotation marks, but still preserved the actually spaces and quotation marks.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be an issue wherein ckeditor does not emit a standard change event when using "Source" mode. Using [a work-around from StackExchange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17358203/how-to-detect-ckeditor-source-mode-on-change-event), we get this proposed fix: https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/5869

We're very close the 4.6.3 release. With some luck, it might get into 4.6.3 -- otherwise, it'll go out with 4.6.4.

Answer (score 1):

I sorted this out:

The CiviCRM won't save changes to an email unless you 1)switch back from the HTML source to the WYSIWYG editor and 2)click somewhere inside the WYSIWYG editor.  Then save the draft, and then it works fine.